# Excel VBA xlDateBetween Throws Application-defined or object-defined error

Tags: vba, excel, date, datetime

I have a datetime column I am trying to filter between and no matter how I try to format it I get Run-time error

> '1004' Application-defined or object-defined error

Here is my code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub filterDate()
''' Manually filters a datetime range '''
Dim hourly_picks As Worksheet
Dim pickCount As PivotTable
Dim picked_at As PivotField
Dim beginDate As Date
Dim endDate As Date



' set variables
Set hourly_picks = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Hourly Pick Count by Employee")
Set pickCount = hourly_picks.PivotTables("PivotTable2")
Set picked_at = pickCount.PivotFields("picked_at")
beginDate = Format(hourly_picks.Range("L2").Value, "M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss")
endDate = Format(hourly_picks.Range("S2").Value, "M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss")    

' clear all filters then filter by picked_at range

pickCount.ClearAllFilters
picked_at.PivotFilters.Add Type:=xlDateBetween, Value1:=beginDate, Value2:=endDate

End Sub
```

My `beginDate` and `endDate` are entered from the user and currently have the values `12/6/2017 23:01:00` and `12/7/2017 7:30:00`. Checking the variables using a `MsgBox` or `Debug.Print` gives `12/6/2017 11:01:00 PM` and `12/7/2017 7:30:00 AM`. The data comes from a postgreSQL database in the format `mm/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss`. If I change the filter column from picked_at to `day_picked` (date that only shows mm/dd/yyyy) then it filters no problem.

Is the issue with the formatting of beginDate/endDate? How can I tell exactly how excel is reading the format of picked_at?

Comment: And if you do `Debug.Print TypeName(hourly_picks.Range("L2").Value)`, do you get `String`, or `Date`?

Comment: On which line is the 1004 error?

Comment: The error occurs on the xlDateBetween line. The below code prints the following: String, Date;

    Debug.Print (TypeName(hourly_picks.Range("L2").Value))
    Debug.Print (TypeName(beginDate))

Answer (score 1):

Update: the issue is *not* with the `.Add` method or with the format/data type of my arguments. I was attempting to filter on a pivot field that was in the filters section of the pivot table. **The only way to filter pivot fields in the filters section is to loop through each pivot item and set Visibility to True or False**. This isn't a solution for me since my pivot field has well over ~17k pivot items so I'll have to find another way.

Additionally I found from researching this problem that using `.Add` isn't correct here -- I should have used `.Add2` instead. From what I found, `.Add2` is for all excel versions 2013 and greater.